Appscript Google sheets returns null
I have 2 sheet on my spreadsheet. My code works with first sheet but when i try with second sheet it returns null. I can't understand why. Also i checked realtime requests it looks returns my data but my sidebar value null still.
function getAllRowsData() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    
    // Get the spreadsheet name
    var spreadsheetName = sheet.getName();
    
    // Get the values of all rows
    var allRows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        
    // Get the column names from the first row
    var columnNames = allRows[0];
    
    // Get the data rows (excluding the header row)
    var dataRows = allRows.slice(1);
    
    var result = { spreadsheetName: spreadsheetName, columns: columnNames, rows: dataRows };
    Logger.log(result);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("An error occurred: " + error.message);
    return null;
  }
}

function getActiveCellValue() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setData).withFailureHandler(function(e){console.error(e)}).withLogger(function(e){console.warn("The following log was generated:"+e)}).getAllRowsData();
        }

I wanted to get my data but it returns null

The function getAllRowsData() is designed to work with the active sheet getActiveSheet(), which means it will only work with the sheet that is currently active i.e., the one you are viewing in the spreadsheet UI. If you're trying to access data from the second sheet but it's not set as the active sheet at the time of running your script, getAllRowsData() will not return the expected data from the second sheet.
Modify getAllRowsData() to accept sheets by name:
function getAllRowsData(sheetName) {
    try {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
        if (!sheet) {
            Logger.log("Sheet not found: " + sheetName);
            return null;
        }
        var spreadsheetName = sheet.getName();
        var allRows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
        var columnNames = allRows[0]
        var dataRows = allRows.slice(1);
        var result = { spreadsheetName: spreadsheetName, columns: columnNames, rows: dataRows };
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        Logger.log("Error occurred: " + error.message);
        return null;
    }
}   

You'll need to modify the function that calls getAllRowsData() to pass sheetName of the sheet you want to access. For example, if you want to access the second sheet and its name is "Sheet2", you would call getAllRowsData("Sheet2").

First of all i choose sheet what i want. And then get getAllRowsData().

You need to give the function getAllRowsData() the name of the spreadsheet of choice as a parameter. If your have 2 spreadsheets and the first is name 'one' and the second is named 'two', you need to call twice getAllRowsData() like this: getAllRowsData(one) and getAllRowsData(two). Make an array of the names of the spreadsheets and call the function for each value.

I didn't work. It still returns null. When i check function call panel it returns my data but js side it's get just null

Did you give the correct name of the spreadsheet to the function?

Yes, as i mention i can see correct when i debug on app script. But when my html call it, returns null

The issue is related to how the client-side code handles the asynchronous call to the Apps Script server function. The code is correct. If you @me creating a new question with the getSheetData() function attached to the question I will be able to debug your issue. Please though accept the answer as valid.
